# How can I make XSL produce the following result given the input XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I've tried several things... using Variables and Templates, and have made some slow progress.  But I'm just not getting this to work - having troubles with my Context.

The input...

- Table '700' can contain multiple entries.
- The values for Subject1, Subject2, Subject3 will be English, Math, Science (But the order may vary from one source XML to another)
- The Scores are positionally ties to the Subject (That is Score1 is for Subject1)

The OutPut...

- Will ALWAYS contain 6 nodes (ENGLISH, MATH, SCIENCE, Class, Class2, Class3)
- The Subject_ tags order ALWAYS needs to be English, Math, then Science.
- The Subject_ tags will be upper cased
- The Subject_ tags will contain a flag of 1 if the corresponding score is > 0; otherwise 0
- The Class_Score tags order order ALWAYS needs to be English, Math, then Science.

I've mangled my code and the following may not be completely functional, but gives a view into what I've tried.

My first question is - am I on the right track?

- Pass Subject to Grades template
- Capture the 'index' of Subject
- Pass Subject and Index to add-Grades-nodes template

This is where my Context issue stops me.

-- My input XML --

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Account Number="123456">
  <Data>
    <Table ID="700">
      <Record ID="1" SubClass="Person">
        <Name.Last>Smith</Name.Last>
        <Name.First>John</Name.First>
        <Score1>50</Score1>
        <Score2>75</Score2>
        <Score3>100</Score3>
        <Subject1>Math</Subject1>
        <Subject2>English</Subject2>
        <Subject3>Science</Subject3>
      </Record>
      <Record ID="2" SubClass="Person">
        <Name.Last>Smith</Name.Last>
        <Name.First>Jane</Name.First>
        <Score1></Score1>
        <Score2>77</Score2>
        <Score3>80</Score3>
        <Subject1>Math</Subject1>
        <Subject2>English</Subject2>
        <Subject3>Science</Subject3>
      </Record>
    </Table>
  </Data>
</Account>
```

-- Desired output XML --

```
<Out>
    <Subject_ENGLISH>1</Subject_ENGLISH>
    <Subject_MATH>1</Subject_MATH>
    <Subject_SCIENCE>1</Subject_SCIENCE>
    <Class_SCORE>75</Class_SCORE>
    <Class2_SCORE>50</Class2_SCORE>
    <Class3_SCORE>100</Class3_SCORE>
    <Subject_ENGLISH>0</Subject_ENGLISH>
    <Subject_MATH>1</Subject_MATH>
    <Subject_SCIENCE>1</Subject_SCIENCE>
    <Class_SCORE></Class_SCORE>
    <Class2_SCORE>77</Class2_SCORE>
    <Class3_SCORE>80</Class3_SCORE>
</Out>
```

-- Current XSLT that does not work --

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="Account">
    <Out>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Account/Data/Table[@ID='700']/Record[@SubClass='Person']>

        <xsl:call-template name="Grades">
          <xsl:with-param name="Subject">English</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="Grades">
          <xsl:with-param name="Subject">Math</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="Grades">
          <xsl:with-param name="Subject">Science</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>


      </xsl:for-each>
    </Out>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="Grades">
    <xsl:param name="Subject"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Subject')][node()=$Subject]">

      <xsl:variable name='cr-index'>
        <xsl:value-of select ='substring(name(), string-length(name()))'/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:call-template name="create-Grades-nodes">
        <xsl:with-param name="cr-context" select =".."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="Subject">
          <xsl:value-of select='$Subject' />
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="cr-index">
          <xsl:value-of select='$cr-index'/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="create-Grades-nodes" match="$cr-context" >
    <xsl:param name ="cr-context"/>
    <xsl:param name ="Subject"/>
    <xsl:param name ="cr-index"/>

    <xsl:variable name='cr-score'>
      <xsl:value-of select='name($cr-context)/concat("Score", $cr-index)'/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

      <xsl:element name='{concat("Subject_", translate($Subject, $smallcase, $uppercase))}'>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test= '$cr-score &gt; 0'>
          <xsl:value-of select = "1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select = "0"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are the nodes always in order? In other words, are you going to get <Score2>50</Score2><Score3>75</Score3><Score1>100</Score1> or <Subject3>Math</Subject3><Subject2>English</Subject2><Subject1>Science</Subject1> ?

Comment: I cannot guarantee the order although I expect they will be in order.  The xml I consume is produced by an outside vendor.

Comment: What is your attempted XSL currently outputting, in contrast to what you want it to output? In other words, what aspect of your desired output are you having trouble with?

Comment: I can get the number off of the Subject# node.  But cannot get to the corresponding Score# node to determine if it has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSubjects">
  <s name="English" at="1"/>
  <s name="Math"    at="2"/>
  <s name="Science" at="3"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vSubjects" select=
 "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pSubjects']/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Out>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Out>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Table[@ID='700']/Record">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Su')]">
    <xsl:sort select="$vSubjects[@name = current()]/@at" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Sc')]">
   <xsl:sort select=
    "$vSubjects[@name
               = current()/../*[starts-with(name(), 'Su')]
                    [substring-after(name(), 'Subject')
                    =
                     substring-after(name(current()), 'Score')
                    ]
                ]/@at"
     data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Su')]">
   <xsl:variable name="vgenName" select=
   "concat('Subject_',
            translate(., $vLower, $vUpper)
           )"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$vgenName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Sc')]">
  <xsl:variable name="vInd" select=
   "$vSubjects[@name
               = current()/../*[starts-with(name(), 'Su')]
                    [substring-after(name(), 'Subject')
                    =
                     substring-after(name(current()), 'Score')
                    ]
                ]/@at"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vgenName" select=
   "concat('Class',
           translate($vInd, '1', ''),
           '_SCORE'
           )
   "/>
   <xsl:element name="{$vgenName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Account Number="123456">
  <Data>
    <Table ID="700">
      <Record ID="1" SubClass="Person">
        <Name.Last>Smith</Name.Last>
        <Name.First>John</Name.First>
        <Score1>50</Score1>
        <Score2>75</Score2>
        <Score3>100</Score3>
        <Subject1>Math</Subject1>
        <Subject2>English</Subject2>
        <Subject3>Science</Subject3>
      </Record>
      <Record ID="2" SubClass="Person">
        <Name.Last>Smith</Name.Last>
        <Name.First>Jane</Name.First>
        <Score1></Score1>
        <Score2>77</Score2>
        <Score3>80</Score3>
        <Subject1>Math</Subject1>
        <Subject2>English</Subject2>
        <Subject3>Science</Subject3>
      </Record>
    </Table>
  </Data>
</Account>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Out>
  <Subject_ENGLISH>English</Subject_ENGLISH>
  <Subject_MATH>Math</Subject_MATH>
  <Subject_SCIENCE>Science</Subject_SCIENCE>
  <Class_SCORE>75</Class_SCORE>
  <Class2_SCORE>50</Class2_SCORE>
  <Class3_SCORE>100</Class3_SCORE>
  <Subject_ENGLISH>English</Subject_ENGLISH>
  <Subject_MATH>Math</Subject_MATH>
  <Subject_SCIENCE>Science</Subject_SCIENCE>
  <Class_SCORE>77</Class_SCORE>
  <Class2_SCORE></Class2_SCORE>
  <Class3_SCORE>80</Class3_SCORE>
</Out>
```

Comment: thank you very much.  You have really taught me a couple neat techniques with XSLT.